# How long did it take to make a 16th century arrow?

Tags: social-history, weapons, early-modern, resource

While researching 16th century arrow making, I read an article on the length of time to produce a complete arrow. My computer crashed before I secured the article, so if anyone can help it would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know but probably a very long time per arrow (I note the last name Arrowsmith implies this was a profession and the scarcity of the name (AFAICT) indicates few people could do it). In the late 1600s (and maybe later), nails were made largely by hand and I think pins were also.

Comment: @Jeff Or they went by [Fletcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher_(surname))?

Comment: @justCal: Ah, good point. But even that name is far less prevalent, afaict, then say, Smith. Anyhow, my point is, it ain't easy to make a functional arrow. Probably even today, a wooden arrow specifically is not made in a completely automated way but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: @Jeff Perhaps, but the Kings of England were placing orders for *hundreds of thousands* of arrows at a a time to be used in France during the Hundred Years War, so it couldn't have been *that* hard to make. 425,000 were bought just in 1421.

Comment: A good [resource](http://www.fletchers.org.uk/historyofarrowmaking.html) (but no answer that I find).

Comment: @Semaphore: I think we know how hard they are to make more or less; obviously they could be made in very large quantities. The making of the requisite straight wooden shaft is something I wonder about. I suspect that is the part and watching on History Channel one of those wilderness guys doing it with a fire and grease to reshape the wood shows me that this was not easy. I wonder if arrows fired in barrages had to be that straight? Aiming was not that important but flight that did not result in losing energy due to wobbling etc was important.

Comment: @justCal Fletching was a separate job, preparing feathers to act as flights and attaching them

Answer (score 6):

For the English longbow my research indicates that arrows were not made by one man or one at a time in the 16th century.   They were mass produced with many craftsmen applying their talents to produce different components which only when assembled would be called an arrow.  So the process wouldn't lend itself to be measured in time per arrow.

> The arrows that were shot from these longbows were a very different story and [required innumerable people to produce all of the components](http://bergental.eastkingdom.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/The-Medieval-and-Tudor-Arrow-A-and-S-II.pdf).

Different kinds artisans who would create an arrow in the 16th century.

- bodkins, or arrow heads were produced by skilled metal workers.
- Shafts were made by yet another artisan.
- Nocks, inserts of bone used to notch the arrow on the bowstring.
- Shapers, after the bodkins and Nocks were applied to the shafts the arrow would be tapered so the fatter part of the shaft would be behind the bodkin.  Modern arrows are parallel,  Sixteen century shafts were not parallel.
- Whipping the shafts and fletching.. arrows in the 16 century would have threads wrapped (whipped) around the shafts
- water proofing the shafts
- Fletchers would split feathers and apply them on shafts.

Comment: Definitely seconding this. Even when making arrows on your own (and I have made quite a number over the years), you are **not** making one arrow, then the next. You prepare a batch of shafts. You cut nocks, one after the other. Then you attach the arrowheads, one after the other. Then you fletch the lot. You want to repeat the same procedure over and over, not continuously hop from one to the next (which involves a change in tools and rearranging your workspace). "How long for one" should be "how many per day and worker", and I would say several dozen, minimum.

Comment: Why would you need to waterproof the shafts?

Comment: @einpoklum a lot of thought was given to storage.  For example,  the glue used for fletching was made of animal sinew.   They would mix compounds into it so that rats and other animals wouldn't eat the glue while the arrows were stored.  I can only imagine that they waterproofed the whipping and shafts in order to prevent warping.   Arrows were made to be stored and still be useful after long periods.

Comment: @DevSolar: !,000 years ago, without power tools, I would think a dozen or so a day would be good production average, specializing each day on a specific task as you describe. Don't forget that the *labour* of every pre-manufactured part, even a making a dowel from a living tree, must be included.

Answer (score 4):

Since you recall reading an article which included the length of time to compllete an arrow, perhaps it was in the book *[With a Bended Bow: Archery in Mediaeval and Renaissance Europe](https://books.google.com/books?id=sveaDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT110&dq=arrow%20production%20100%20years%20war&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjin-D5m4DYAhVK3mMKHYUKD-IQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=arrow%20production%20100%20years%20war&f=false)* By Erik Roth.  In this text, there is a section on manufacturing, which details the time involved to *reproduce* arrows such as those found in [Nydam Bog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nydam_Mose).  The time arrived at is about 2 hours per arrow, including:

- 50 minutes to cut the shaft
- 30 minutes for fletching
- 15 minutes for attaching the arrowhead
- 25 minutes to make the arrowhead itself

Of course this would be a conservative time estimate, since an organization such as [The Worshipful Company of Fletchers](http://www.fletchers.org.uk/index.html), which was one of the famous [Livery Companies of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livery_company) would have had the organization and power to increase production rates, especially at time of war.

These sheaf arrows would have been produced in a 'guild' situation, with masters overseeing apprentices and laborers working all stages of production concurrently, and as with any craft, 'tricks of the trade' would have increased the production rate in ways we can only guess at.  This figure does provide, however an appreciation of the time and labor involved.

Comment: arrowheads like this one : https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-hCl9EmwY0Ao/WXCkejOqmuI/AAAAAAAAAuc/YYTLAxckez4ynUSd53iKS51qGeTltaORQCEwYBhgL/s1600/Crossbow%2BBolt_EPI_Wentworth.jpg can take less than 10 minutes per piece, 5 if it can e directly molded against the shaft. as personal experience with a forge & hammer.

Comment: @CptEric Is that in modern forge setting, or simulated medieval gear?  I did see another report of reproducing arrows for use with reproduction English long bows, which said you (modern craftsman) could expect to craft a dozen arrows per day, but no definition on length of day. (and I suspect using precast broadheads).

Comment: just iron bars, a hammer, a smithing "stuff" where you hit, and a forge fire. you need 4-8 hits to get the "head" done, (non-polished finish) plus only a dozen or so to make the cone shaft cover. if you have the shafts nearby, you can smith the metal directly around it, with the heat and water expanding the wood quickly and fixing it. not perfect, and would maybe need two or three grind wheel turns to make it sharp pointed, but it's fast and it surely kills. i did it on a friend's forge, but with enough iron and shafts, i could do way more than a dozen. not the fletching part tho.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Bh8iOvlaxw  <- someone doing it with care. you can be less "careful" with the materials if you're in a hurry. or make them piercing square instead of broad.

Comment: ofcourse you need a very strong fire to do so, but not explicitly an industrial modern one. i've seen medieval-style forge fires turn steel bars in lightsabers less than a minute due to good air flow and strong arms of the "helpboy" at the air fueling stuff. imagine having a blood-driven engine ( horse or donkey) fueling all around and automating the process a bit.

Comment: @CptEric Interesting stuff. The [bodkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodkin_point) shape does seem natural, just tapering the square rod. The video shows about 4 minutes, but cuts out forge time, so perhaps 8 minutes per arrowhead? As I mentioned, I'm sure these old tradesmen could beat the listed sources times with the specialized labor and production in a specialized shop dedicated to the production of arrows.

Comment: @CptEric: If you're looking at speed, consider casting bronze arrowheads. I've seen reenactors doing bronze casting with nothing but a firepit, charcoal, a hand-powered bellows arrangement, an earthen pot and a pair of pliers. With a proper mold, you could do ~10  arrowheads per batch with no more than what you could carry on your back. And a well-done bronze is good enough for an arrowhead unless you're looking at plate armor.

Comment: @DevSolar: Wasn't bronze rarer than iron in the 16th century? Also, Bronze is an alloy; doesn't that slow you down?

Comment: @einpoklum: The naval artillery of the time was cast bronze, so not exactly "rare". It is an alloy of (mostly) copper and tin, which is comparatively easy to make -- if you have the tin. As you can cast bronze into a functional arrowhead in a way you cannot do with iron (cast iron is brittle, and anyhow requires much higher temperatures), I could imagine you could make more arrowheads in the same amount of time. Then again, I am neither a metalworker nor am I really "into" that particular time period, so... a grain of salt.

Comment: In the middle ages you have to start with live birds (for fletching), and living trees (for shafts and glue), and calculate "*labour*" (or cost equivalent) of every single darn step before the arrow is a finished product. There is no **Lansing Build-All** down the road a few minutes where supplies can be purchased.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Check [this article](https://books.google.com/books?id=vMtHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA511&dq=king+ordering+every+goose+plucked+for+feathers+100+years+war&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW0tyuvIPYAhWLyoMKHXICCV8Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=king%20ordering%20every%20goose%20plucked%20for%20feathers%20100%20years%20war&f=false) (right column) out concerning obtaining feathers during the 100 Years war...

Comment: @DevSolar i've done bronze and lead casting, it's fun  but it tends to make "bubbles" depending on the temperature of the liquid metal and the porosity of the cast, so sometimes you loose a whole batch.  as for the materials said by pieter, well, you can be 100% sure a metalsmith would not need to know how to fletch or go hunting ducks for feathers. he'd be in charge, at best, to either make heads, or make & attach heads.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Even in the middle ages you'd get feathers from those who herd geese, arrowheads from the smith, and thread from the spinner. A fletcher would not hunt geese in the morning, work bellows at noon and turn the spinning wheel in the evening.

Comment: @justCal: That is *to supply a campaign in France*; not yield arrows for the domestic training of practice of a longbowman. Did you note the "*Yew bows were prohibited being used by anyone under the age of seventeen whose father was not worth ten pounds a year in land, or forty marks in goods.*" in [your link](https://books.google.ca/books?id=vMtHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA511&dq=king+ordering+every+goose+plucked+for+feathers+100+years+war&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=king%20ordering%20every%20goose%20plucked%20for%20feathers%20100%20years%20war&f=false).